# Problem implementing threads in a program

Tags: c++

I have the following program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/thread/thread_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class DogDoor {
    bool open;
public:
    DogDoor()
    {
        this->open = false;
    }
    void Open()
    {
        cout << "The dog door opens" << endl << endl;
        open = true;
    }
    void close()
    {
        cout << "The dog door closes" << endl << endl;
        open = false;
    }
    bool isOpen()
    {
        return open;
    }
};

class Remote {
    DogDoor* door;
public:
    Remote(DogDoor* door)
    {
        this->door = door;
    }
    void pressButton()
    {
        cout << "Pressing the remote button" << endl;
        if(door->isOpen())
        {
            door->close();
        }
        else
        {
            door->Open();
            // close after 5 seconds
            boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(5);
            boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);
            door->close();
        }
    }
};

void threadFunc(Remote* r)
{
    r->pressButton();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DogDoor* door = new DogDoor();
    Remote* remote = new Remote(door);

    cout << "Fido barks to go outside" << endl;
    boost::thread workerThread(threadFunc, remote);

    cout << "Fido has gone outside" << endl;

    cout << "Fido is all done..." << endl;

    cout << "Fido is back inside" << endl;

    workerThread.join();

    delete door;
    delete remote;

    return 0;
}
```

I want the program to print:

```
Fido barks to go outside
Pressing the remote button
The dog door opens
Fido has gone outside
Fido is all done...
Fido is back inside
// and then after 5 seconds it should print this
The dog door closes
```

But my implementation it will print like this and I don't know how to make it print good:

```
Fido barks to go outside
Fido has gone outside
Fido is all done...
Fido is back inside
Pressing the remote button
The dog door opens
// this after 5 seconds
The dog door closes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the main thread wait until the door is open:

```
class DogDoor 
{
    bool open;
public:
    // If you want to go through this door you should call
    // this method. If the door is not open you are suspended.
    // until somebody opens the door.
    void goThroughDoor()
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
        while(!open)
        {
            // Note this is a while loop here.
            // Just because all the waiting threads are un-sespended when the
            // door is opened, it does not mean that they will get scheduled
            // to run before the door closes. So after the thread wakes up and
            // starts to run we need to re-check if the door is still open.
            //
            // If it took to long to wake up, then we have to wait again for
            // the door to be opened.
            //
            // Thus this would be a good place to bark.
            // Which may cause the remote button to be pushed.
            //
            waiter.wait(mut);
        }
    }


    DogDoor()
    {
        this->open = false;
    }
    void Open()
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
        cout << "The dog door opens" << endl << endl;
        open = true;

        waiter.notify_all();
    }
    void close()
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
        cout << "The dog door closes" << endl << endl;
        open = false;
    }
    bool isOpen()
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
        return open;
    }


    private:
        boost::condition_variable waiter;
        boost::mutex              mut;

};
```

Now you need to modify main to make sure the dog calls goThroughDoor().

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DogDoor* door = new DogDoor();
    Remote* remote = new Remote(door);

    cout << "Fido barks to go outside" << endl;
    boost::thread workerThread(threadFunc, remote);

    // This will suspend this thread if the door is locked.
    // When the door is opened the thread will resume.    
    door->goThroughDoor();


    cout << "Fido has gone outside" << endl;

    // Should check the door is open
    // When Fido tries to come in. If it is closed he will be suspended.
    // And thus will not get back in. (Note he should have a way of barking
    // if he is blocked but that I leave to you).    
    door->goThroughDoor();
    cout << "Fido is all done..." << endl;

    cout << "Fido is back inside" << endl;

    workerThread.join();

    delete door;
    delete remote;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Nothing says your started thread has to execute right away; it might not be scheduled to run until the `join()` call explicitly drops the CPU. While you could try calling Boost's moral equivalent of `yield()`, in full-fledged programs nothing would guarantee that the thread you *want* to run actually *would* run.

To ensure that you wait for the child thread to execute, you'll need to use some [thread synchronization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html) tools, such as a mutex or condition variable, so that your child thread can signal the main thread that it has finished the task. If you move the call to `join()` closer to where you spawn the program, you can be sure the thread has finished, but this might only work for a toy application. In non-trivial applications, you'll need to use a [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex) or [condition variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) to signal specific "job done" conditions between threads.

Answer (score 3):

First, it's worth noting that from most viewpoints, this is nearly the worst possible use of threads/threading. In particular, neither thread can actually do much of anything on its own -- everything in one thread requires synchronization with something in the other thread.

That's pretty much the problem you're running into -- you haven't synchronized everywhere you need to. Your sequence needs to look something like this:

```
Fido barks
ask door to open
wait for confirmation that door has opened
Fido leaves
Fido returns
ask door to close
wait for confirmation that door has closed
join
exit
```

Essentially every action in one thread depends on something in the other thread, so even though you have two threads, none of it can execute in parallel.